# button is missing or outside of body

Tags: html, css

```css
body{
position:relative;
width:200px;
margin:0 auto;
background:gold;
}

.btn{
position:absolute;
right:10px;
bottom:0;
background:blue;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<button class='btn'>SEND</button>
```

why `body` in code snippet is not `200px`?

where is `btn` in code snippet?

On my localhost `body` IS 200px and `btn` is there but outside of body (seams as his parent is `html` and not `body`.

Any help?

Comment: It appears to be in the middle, but above the canvas

Comment: You've set your button to display 10px from the right of the screen.

Comment: @DanielWilliamsn, no it should be `10px` right from body.

Comment: give the body height.

Comment: @Pengcheng it is here already 100% (from some reason)

Comment: because of .btn bottom:0; if you don't change the height, you can only see the button on the bottom of the body. not sure where you want to put the button, you can also change the position of the button, for instance: top: 50 vh; // 50%. By the way, actually the body has a height 0 not 100%.

Comment: @Pengcheng, how it is possible? `body` is `backgorund:gold` and you can see entire page is `gold`?

Comment: if you open your code snippet in full page and inspect the element you will see the height of the body is zero, you need to set the height value. but the body background color will fill the page background if the element html has no background. if you set the html background, you will not see the gold anymore util you set the height of the body. By the way, using border to determine the scope of the element better than background, and if you just set the color, using backgroung-color instead of backgroud.

Comment: you must have to add a body height, 100% is not ok without any element in the body

Answer (score 1):

Here you are confused by a specific behavior of the background which is background propagation from `body` to canvas which make you thing that what you see is the whole `body`.

> For documents whose root element is an HTML HTML element or an XHTML
>   html element [HTML]: if the computed value of background-image on the
>   root element is none and its background-color is transparent, user
>   agents must instead propagate the computed values of the background
>   properties from that element’s first HTML BODY or XHTML body child
>   element. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#special-backgrounds)</sup>

If you add a background color to the `html` element this one will get used and you will no more see the gold

```css
html {
  background: red;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: gold;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class='btn'>SEND</button>
```

Now it's clear the body is not visible simply because its height is 0 since there is no in-flow element inside it as the button is position absolute. Considering this, `bottom:0` is the top of you screen and you button is overflowing from the top.

Let's add some animation to see it:

```css
html {
  background: red;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: gold;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  transition:1s;
}
html:hover .btn {
  bottom:-50px;
}
```

```html
<button class='btn'>SEND</button>
```

And to make sure that your body is having a width equal to `200px` and a height 0 simply add a border and you will see it. You will also notice the background propagation

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: gold;
  border:5px solid;
  padding:1px;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  transition:1s;
}
body:hover .btn {
  bottom:-50px;
}
```

```html
<button class='btn'>SEND</button>
```

As you can see the body behave exactly like you want (centred with 200px width) and by adding a small padding and border we can also see that the button is placed at the bottom right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply some of the properties to both your `body` and `html` because there is no content to apply your `height: 100%` to.

Try applying a border on your body to see how 'big' it is. If you do not set a height to you `html` at the same time, you will see that it has no height because of the lack of content.

```css
body, html {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
  background: gold;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class='btn'>SEND</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must have to add a body height, 100% is not ok without any element in the body

try this CSS code

```css
body{
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:gold;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    height: 100px; /* this height for example */
}

.btn{
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    bottom:0;
    background:blue;
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code

```css
body {
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:gold;
}
.btn {
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  bottom:0;
  background:blue;
  color:white;
  top: 0;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<button class='btn'>SEND</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you havent mentioned what end result you want. I have assumed few things and worked accordingly. Since all the absolute elements are by default related to body. The position relative to the body is not making any difference. Plus if you want a 200px width of the button container, its better to use a div here with max-width:200.Try the code below make changes accordingly. Hope it helps !!

CSS:

```
body{
//Removed everything
}

.btn{
position:absolute;
width:60px;height:20px;
top:50%;left:50%;
margin-top:-10px;margin-left:-30px;
background:blue;
color:white;
}
.button_holder{
  position:relative;margin: 50px auto;
  max-width:200px;height:100px;
  background:gold;
}
```

Markup :

```
<div class="button_holder">
  <button class='btn'>SEND</button>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MPvLqE

Comment: thanks. there is a lot of way to do what I want. But here I need the following: why is the button in code snippet - hidden? And why the body is not `200px` but `100%` width?

Comment: body is the whole body.. I guess we cannot play around with its dimensions. It is always 100% and your button is not hidden in the code snippet it has just moved 10px to the top.. This must be due to conflict with the code snippets own code.

Comment: `Since all the absolute elements are by default related to body. The position relative to the body is not making any difference` --> this is false, a positioned element is positioned relatively to the first positioned ancestor and if there is not it's then the viewport and not the body .. remove position:relative from his code and you will see a big difference